How to change default font size of rem in MUI
All styles are based on rem in my application and I would love to let everything looks a bit smaller.
So I need to change the default font size of rem from 16px to 14px or 13px.
Based on MUI docs, All we need to do is just to change fontSize or htmlFontSize in typography, like this:
export const createTypographyOptions = (): TypographyOptions => {
    const thinFontWeight = 300
    const regularFontWeight = 400
    const mediumFontWeight = 500

    const pixelsToRem = (pixels: number) => `${pixels / 16}rem`

    return {
        fontSize: 12,
        h1: {
            fontWeight: thinFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(48),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(52),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
        h2: {
            fontWeight: thinFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(36),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(48),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
        h3: {
            fontWeight: regularFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(32),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(40),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
        h4: {
            fontWeight: regularFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(28),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(36),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
        h5: {
            fontWeight: regularFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(24),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(32),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
        h6: {
            fontWeight: mediumFontWeight,
            fontSize: pixelsToRem(22),
            lineHeight: pixelsToRem(28),
            letterSpacing: '0em',
        },
    }
}

But it works for all other elements except h1 - h6, but h1 - h6 still has rem size of 16px.
I tried to set fontSize smaller or htmlFontSize bigger in typography following this doc: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#font-size, but it doesn't work as what I stated above.
I want the font size to be applied to all elements.
